# Using 3D touch in Sprite Kit to measure pressure

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 3dtouch, force-touch

In my main app I'm trying to use 3D touch to activate a bullet fireing, but the results seem to be very inconsistant and it didn't always give my the write results. Also my iPhone 6S was crashing when I used this code, This is the code I used for a test.

```
 for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        var force =  touch.force * 10
        var maxForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce

        print ("The force is")
        print (maxForce*4)
        print (force*10000000)

        if force != 0{


            myLabel.text = "Force"
            myLabel.fontSize = 45
            myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
            self.addChild(myLabel)
            myLabel.zPosition = 100000


        }

        else {

           myLabel.removeFromParent()
        }
```

Comment: At which point is it crashing??

Answer (score 0):

I am a going to guess it is crashing because you add label to the parent multiple times (Your if condition is broken,  no matter what function you call, (`touchesBegan`,`touchesMoved`,`touchesEnded`) only one of those conditions will always be true, in `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`, your force will always be > 0, in your `touchEnded`, your force should be 0. (I am going to assume this code is your `touchMoved`)  Instead, add your label in the your viewDidLoad code,  and use the .hidden field to show/hide your label on your moves. (Make sure on `touchesEnded` to hide it)